# Piecewise function notation and applications

Tags: functions, notation

I would like to define a piecewise function to imitate some physical phenomenon, which, for example, occurs once in a year (at June for a whole month long). Say, frequency/domain (integers) of the func is representing months, and January is at 0. 
How to say mathematically, that *y=0 if x is not a member of positive Z which are divisible by smth* (to imitate all months except for June) and *y=1 if x is a member of pos. Z which are divisible by smth* (to imitate June)?
For me here the problem also is that I cannot easily say that it is y=1 for all integers divisible by 6-1 (6 as a June and -1 to compensate for starting with January at 0) because it would also cover next January etc.

Comment: To confirm, you want the function to output $1$ at $5$ (for June) and $17$ (for the next June), etc.?

Comment: Exactly. And I would also like to know how to notate it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $0$ corresponds to January, numbers that correspond to June are $5$, $17$, $22$, etc. That sequence increases by $12$ each time, so the difference between any two of them is some multiple of $12$. And because of this, if we divide any of them by $12$, we'll get an integer quotient representing the number of years, and a remainder of $5$.

One understandable, but nonstandard way to write your function would be something like:
$$f(n)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if the remainder of }n\div12\text{ is }5\\
0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

There is a special language and notation for dealing with things like this, in the words of so-called "[modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)". Two integers whose difference is a multiple of $12$ are said to be "congruent modulo $12$", and we use the notation $n_1\equiv n_2\pmod {12}$ in math.

A more standard notation would be something like:
$$f(n)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if }n\equiv5\pmod{12}\\
0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

In *some* mathematics subfields, functions that are $1$ or $0$ in this way are common, and there are special notations like the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) or [indicator functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function). But  these may not be universally understood.

Finally, in programming-related contexts, the calculation of the remainder is emphasized more than the equivalence, so they would be more likely to write things in terms of the [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) which outputs the remainder.

Comment: Such an easy and brilliant solution. Thank you!